# Why does the compiler look for a default constructor for my exception class?

Tags: c++, default-constructor

I've defined a small exception hierarchy for my library. It inherits from *std::runtime_error*, like this:

```
class library_exception : public std::runtime_error {
    using std::runtime_error::runtime_error;
};

class specific_exception : public library_exception {
    int guilty_object_id;

    specific_exception(int guilty_object_id_)
        : guilty_object_id(guilty_object_id_) {}
};
```

The compiler says:

> error: call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of 'library_exception'

and points to the *specific_exception* constructor.

Why is it trying to call the default constructor here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`library_exception` inherits from `std::runtime_error`. The latter does not have a default constructor, which means the former isn't default constructable.

Similarly, `specific_exception` isn't default constructable because its base class isn't. You need a default constructor for the base here because the base is implicitly initialized:

```
specific_exception(int guilty_object_id_)
    : guilty_object_id(guilty_object_id_) {}
```

To fix this, call the appropriate base class constructor:

```
specific_exception(int guilty_object_id_)
    : library_exception("hello, world!"),
      guilty_object_id(guilty_object_id_) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Retracted:** *This answer was misguided. (The constructors referred to are actually used in default initialization of class members, not the class itself.)*

*std::runtime_error* has a string field, something like this:

```
class runtime_error {
    std::string msg;

public:
    runtime_error(std::string msg) : msg(msg) { }
};
```

*msg* is not initialized by your constructor (and can't be, since the field's private). Therefore the default constructor is invoked. More precisely,

> default initialization […] is the initialization performed when a variable is constructed with no initializer.
>
> …
>
> Default initialization is performed in three situations:
>
> …
>
> 3) when a base class or a non-static data member is not mentioned in a constructor initializer list and that constructor is called.
>
> The effects of default initialization are:
>
> …
>
> If T is a […] class type, the constructors are considered and subjected to overload resolution against the empty argument list. The constructor selected (which is one of the default constructors) is called to provide the initial value for the new object.

([cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization))

However, I still don't get why it's complaining about the base class *library_exception* instead of *specific_exception*. Adding an argument-less constructor in *specific_exception* doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Isn't the default constructor deleted when one of the base classes' default constructor is deleted? so `library_exception` has a deleted default constructor. Note: I can't quote the standard here